# parsing small file performance

Tags: javascript, sql, parsing

Suppose I have a file of a dictionnary with 30.000 lines (naturally string sorted), stored in some `json` file. I want the user to input some character and then autocomplete dynamically his input relatively to the dictionnary. What would be the best strategy to do that :

- divide this `json` file into small `json` file chunks and then specify the called `url` depending on the first character, making the ajax call hits a file of ~1000 lines (in any way this solution looks bad and is not maintainable)
- put this file in some `sql` table, index it and the call it through `ajax`

Obviously, for huge files the second way is the better, but for small files, sure the search algorithm are much faster with indexation but calling the whole daba machinery on each key stroke is perhaps not the best way.

Comment: First thing to do is see what it's like to just serve up a gzip'ed version of the whole dictionary. Make sure it's a static URL so that clients can keep a cached version.

Comment: I would at least split it based on the first 2 characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues here. There doesn't need to be any correlation between how the data is stored and how it is served. Usually there is no correlation between the two for data.

I agree with Pointy that the first thing you should do is the very simple solution of serving the whole file and acting on it client-side only. Evaluate the size of the file served and performance. Is this sufficient for your needs? If so, don't optimize unnecessarily.

*Note: When testing performance make sure you have a production size data set with realistic variance and range of data.*

If this is not good enough, you need to identify what the bottleneck is. Is it the lookup on the client side? Is it the data transfer? Is the data transferred onload or on first need? If on first need is it reasonable to transfer it earlier? Does that solve the problem?

If the problem is indeed transferring the amount of data from server to client, then write a smart server side handler that stores the data in memory in chunks, usually by first letter or first two letters, and serves those chunks as needed. Make sure each chunk can be individually cached (proper cache headers).

If the problem is not transferring but client side processing (which is very likely), look at how you're storing the data in the JSON file. It will likely benefit to create indexes where when you first load the data, loop through it and create new lists of all items starting with each first letter, then all items starting with two letter combinations and then when you access what you need you can use these lists, like this:

```
var oneLetterIndex = {};
oneLetterIndex['a'] = [items starting with a...]
oneLetterIndex['b'] = [items starting with b...]
...
// do the above dynamically of course..
```

Then evaluate, and if need more performance, do the same for two letters..

```
var twoLetterIndex = {};
twoLetterIndex['aa'] = [...];
twoLetterIndex['ab'] = [...];
...
twoLetterIndex['zz'] = [...];
// again, do dynamically and skip the two letter combos that don't exist in data
```

Comment: These articles by John Resig: [dictionary lookup](http://ejohn.org/blog/dictionary-lookups-in-javascript/) and [trie performance](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-trie-performance-analysis/) may also be helpful